# Best practice to implement messages from one location in C#

Tags: c#

I have to manage messages content of dialog message box at one place in my winform application,
my main concern is that, that all content should be at one place, so programmer can easily access it and don't create duplicate messages in each code file and second thing is that it easily locate these messages, Now I can manage it by :

1.By **app config** file, but if I place all massages over app config than there will be "n" number of keys for messages and it will mess-up app config as readability point of view .

2. **By using Class**, create one class "MessageConstant" and place all messages inside this class but again by this also, all messages are inside flat class it will mess-up, there is no categorization, divide a region inside class on the bases of category .
3. **By using class and than create class inside class as category wise** and place these constant inside these classes .

I am little confuse to it that, which is a best practice, can any guide me on this point, how it should be implemented .

Comment: I usually create a `Resource.resx` file to store all my string literals.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the built in Resources. This will enable you to reference them in C# via the generated code members, and also builds in translation capabilities for later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the first option you can use a special feature of config files that allows you to specify sections in separate files:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
</configuration>
```

This way your main `app.config` file is still lean and readabale and all the messages live in a separate files. This gives you the option of changing the text without recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use constants and categorize the messages, you can create multiple classes inside:

```
public class Messages 
{
    public class Errors 
    { 
        public const string UnspecifiedError = "An unspecified error has occurred";
    }

    public class Others
    {
       public const string Something = "Some other message";
    }
}
```

But I really recommend you to use Resources instead. That way you can implement localization easily when needed. You can also create multiple resources, so you can have one for error messages and other for whatever other category you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of messages, retrieve them from the database. That's the best practice I can think of.

Give them ids, types and module based specifications if needed.

Then create a simple class to retrieve from database by their ID's.